# Customize ggplot axis text

Tags: r, dataframe, ggplot2

I would like to customize the legend of the above plot. Basically, I would like the x values of the dashed lines to define specific items in the legend. For example the dashed line at time step `"11:00"` is coloured by `"#00CC66"` (green colour). I would like to have in the legend an 'X' colored by green color (eg. `"#00CC66"`). Another example, the dashed line at time step `"12:00"` is colored by`"#FF3333"` (red color).I would like to have in the legend an 'X' colored by red color. (eg.`"#FF3333"`)

[image]

Comment: Please post your code, and the data frame you used on this graph (post the output from the `dput(df)` function, where `df` is the data frame).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OP.  What you are looking to apply color to specifically appears to be from your description the *axis text*, rather than the legend.  Without your particular dataset, I can only show you how you can do this generally, and then leave it up to you to apply to your particular case.

The color of the axis text is a `theme` element, and is controlled by `axis.text` generally (for both axes), or `axis.text.x` / `axis.text.y` for the x and y axes separately.  Addressing and changing aspects of the text on both axes will require you to specify `element_text()` within `theme()`.  It looks generally like this in a typical plotting code:

```
ggplot(...) + geom_...() + theme(
    axis.text.x = element_text(color = 'blue', face = 'bold', size = 12, angle=20)
  )
```

This particular case above would make the x axis text all blue in color, size 12, bold, and set the angle at 20 degrees.

To specify *parts* of the axis to have different color, size, face, etc therefore has to access this `theme` element.  The important thing to keep in mind is that `theme` elements are not mapped in the same way that the rest of your plot and geoms are mapped - which is through `aes()`.  In place of `color = 'blue'`, you can either pass one value (which is applied to all), or you can supply a character vector *which is the same length as the labels on your axis*.  **<-- this point is very important to remember**.

Here's an example.

```
set.seed(1234)
df <- data.frame(
  x=1:20,
  y=rnorm(20)
)
```

Let's create a simple plot:

```
p <- ggplot(df, aes(x,y)) + geom_point() + theme_bw() +
  geom_hline(yintercept=0, linetype=2) +
  scale_x_continuous(breaks=1:20)
p
```

[image]

If you wanted to color the axis labels based on criteria, you can directly code that into `theme(axis.text.x = element_blank(color=...` in such a way that creates a character vector of colors.  Remember, there's no mapping here, so make sure that the order of the resulting vector follows the same order of your dataset.  If in your case your x values are not ordered in the original dataset, you will need them to be for this to work properly.  Here's how you can cause the x axis labels to be colored differently for negative vs. positive values of `df$y`:

```
p + theme(
    axis.text.x = element_text(color=ifelse(df$y < 0,'red', 'gray80'))
  )
```

[image]

You can even get more complicated with this method, but as long as the resulting character vector is in the same order as the axis labels, it should work:

```
p + theme(
    axis.text.x = element_text(
      color=ifelse(df$y < 0,'red', 'gray80'),
      size=ifelse(abs(df$y) > 1, 18, 8),
      face=ifelse(abs(df$y) > 1, 'bold', 'italic')
    )
  )
```

[image]